# Working with XeLaTeX and Pygments

Tags: fonts, xetex

I am trying to use XeLaTeX typesetting engine together with [Pygments](http://pygments.org/) syntax highlighter. XeLaTex enables me to use all the fonts that are available to the operating system; Pygments helps me to color the code.

I added the following two lines into the LaTeX file generated by Pygments.

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Monaco}
```

I was expecting to see the final PDF file with colored code in Monaco font, but I didn't. How can I edit the latex file generated by Pygments in order to specify my desired fonts?

Monaco font looks like this:

[image]

But I was getting the something like this (screenshot of the PDF file generated by XeLaTex):

[image]

---

[This problem is solved, thanks to the comment of @TorbjørnT.]

Comment: Does `\setmonofont{Monaco}` instead of `\setmainfont{Monaco}` help?

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: Please turn your comment into an answer, and add the necessary detail to make the solution comprehensible to future readers.

Comment: @Werner Will do.

Comment: @Ning: It would also be great if you'd mention whether you use Pygments directly or _via_ the `minted` package.

Comment: @JosephWright I used Pygments separately. But, thanks for mentioning the minted package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When choosing fonts with `fontspec` you have to use different commands for the different families, "normal" serif fonts, sans serif fonts, monospaced fonts. A typical setup may be

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont{Linux Biolinum O}
\setmonofont{Inconsolata}
```

which will use *Linux Libertine O* as the standard, serif, font of the document, *Linux Biolinum O* as the sans serif font, and *Inconsolata* as the monospace font.

The font family used for code listings is the monospaced one, `\ttfamily`, and as such it is `\setmonofont` that influences it. Hence, you should use

```
\setmonofont{Monaco}
```

---

One small addendum: If you're going to be writing a document with several listings, you might consider using the [`minted`](http://ctan.org/pkg/minted) package, which uses Pygments. (Another package that provides syntax highlighted code listings is [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings).)

Instead of the mess created by

```
pygmentize -f latex -O full -l python code.py > code.tex
```

you can have a document such as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{python}
def(hallais):
     print("Hello TeX.sx!")
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

or instead of the `minted` environment, you can input a file with your code, *e.g.*,

```
 \inputminted[linenos=true]{python}{demo.py}
```

This needs to be compiled with `-shell-escape` enabled, *e.g.*,

```
xelatex -shell-escape filename.tex
```

See the `minted` manual for more details.

Comment: This is a great help!